# Declaring a positional argument inside a group of optional arguments in Python

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I want to use `argparse` in Python to declare arguments as the following:

```
./get_efms_by_ids [-h] [-v] [inputfile [1 3 4 9] [-c 11..18] [20 25 40]]
```

What I want to do in this case are: 
If `inputfile` is used, one can take two type of optional arguments: `1 3 4 9` or `c 11..18` or both of them. If I do not enter `inputfile`, the optional arguments must be absent.

For example:
I can show you some examples of command line usage:

```
./get_efms_by_ids Vacf.txt // default: get 1 or 10 first lines in Vacf.txt
./get_efms_by_ids Vacf.txt 1 3 4 9 // get the lines that indexes: 1 3 4 9 in Vacf.txt
./get_efms_by_ids Vacf.txt c 11..18 22 25 29 // get the lines that indexes are from 11 to 18, then the lines 22, 25, 29
./get_efms_by_ids c 11.. 18 // shows a readable error message
./get_efms_by_ids 1 3 4 9 // shows a readable error message
```

One can use `args='?'` or `args='*'` like in the following example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Selecting some Elementary Flux Modes by indexes.',version='1.0')
parser.add_argument('efm_matrix_file', type=file, help='give the name of the efms matrix file')
parser.add_argument('ids', nargs='?', help='give the indexes of the chosen efms')
parser.add_argument('-i','--indexes',nargs='*', help='give the begin and start indexes of the chosen efms')
```

But the result did not satisfy with the purpose have proposed in the beginning of this post.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. My guess would be that `inputfile` is optional, but if it is there, you want none, some, or all of the following, in order: one of 1, 3, 4, 9; `-c` with one argument between 11 and 18 inclusive; and one of 20, 25, 40?

Comment: @chepner: `inputfile` would be optional. Actually, I want to know that `inputfile` is not used, the rest optional arguments will be absent. In other words, they are dependent on `inputfile`. I use `-c 11..18` to get all lines that indexes range 11 to 18. If using 1,3,4,9 etc., I want to get the individual elements.

Comment: What you want is the arguments group: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argument-groups

Comment: Argument groups don't affect parsing; they just organize arguments in the help message.

Comment: Would you please give examples of command line usage?

Comment: @HaiVu: Could you see in the post, I have just modified it by explaining more clearly.

Comment: `type=file` is wrong.  `type` takes a function that converts a string into something else.  I'd suggest accepting a filename (string) and opening that later.

Comment: @hpaulj: `type=file` is fine, as well as `type=argparse.FileType()`. `type=file` will convert the file name from the command line into a readable file object.

Comment: I've always used `open`, which `file` itself describes as the preferred way.  In either case, there are problems with opening a file in `argparse`.  http://bugs.python.org/issue13824

Comment: Python3 has dropped `file` as a synonym for `open`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would ditch the `-c` option. You don't need both `-c` and `..` to indicate a range of values. This would simplify your call to something like

```
./get_efms_by_ids [-h] [-v] [inputfile [index ...]]
```

where each `index` can be either a single integer or a range specified by `lower..upper`.

The argument parser could then be a simple as

```
def index_type(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return map(int, s.split(".."))
        except:
            raise ArgumentTypeError("Invalid index: %s" % (s,))

p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-h")
p.add_argument("-v")
p.add_argument("inputfile", nargs="?")
p.add_argument("indices", nargs="*", type=index_type)
args = p.parse_args()

if not (args.inputfile is None or os.path.exists(args.inputfile)):
    sys.exit("Invalid file name: %s" % (args.inputfile,))
```

You'll have to check that the first positional argument (if any) is a valid file or not *after* parsing, since any arbitrary string *could* be a valid file name.

The `index_type` function is just an example of how you could transform each index (whether an integer or range) during the course of parsing.

Comment: I cannot control error if one uses `./get_efms_by_ids 11 14 16` without the `inputfile`. It does not jump to `ArgumentError()` either.

Comment: I replaced `ArgumentError` with a simple `sys.exit`, since `ArgumentError` is really intended to be raised from with `parse_args` (it expects an actual argument object as one of its arguments).

Comment: I get the error messages:
`File "/usr/local/bin/get_efms_by_ids.py", line 52, in main
    if not(args.inputfile is None or os.path.isfile(args.inputfile)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 29, in isfile
    st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`

Comment: I don't see how you could get that error from the code I posted.

Comment: I apologize with the comment. I made a wrong syntax.

Comment: `parser.error('message')` can be used to print usage, error message and sys exit.

Answer (score 1):

I take a different approach from chepner, but borrow some of chepner's ideas: ditching the `-c` option and use a modified `index_type()`.

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
from itertools import chain

def index_type(s):
    try:
        return [int(s)]
    except ValueError:
        try:
            start, stop = map(int, s.split('..'))
            return range(start, stop + 1)
        except:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Invalid index: %s" % (s,))

def get_options():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v')
    parser.set_defaults(fileinput=None)

    options, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
    if remaining:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('fileinput', type=argparse.FileType())
        parser.add_argument('selected_lines', nargs='*', type=index_type)
        parser.parse_args(remaining, namespace=options)

        # Convert a nested list into a set of line numbers
        options.selected_lines = set(chain.from_iterable(options.selected_lines))

        # If the command line does not specify the line numbers, assume a default
        if not options.selected_lines:
            options.selected_lines = set(index_type('1..10'))

    return options

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = get_options()

    # If the command line contains a file name, loop through the file and process only the lines
    # requested
    if options.fileinput is not None:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(options.fileinput, 1):
            if line_number in options.selected_lines:
                line = line.rstrip()
                print '{:>4} {}'.format(line_number, line)
```

## Discussion

- The argparse module allows for optional argument, but fileinput cannot be optional because it is a positional argument--that is how argparse operates
- To get around this limitation, I parse the command line twice: the first time to get the `-v` flag. For the first parsing, I use the `parse_known_args()` method, which ignores those parameters it does not understand.
- For the second parsing, I work on the remaning arguments, assuming the first argument is the file name, followed by a series of lines numbers
- Parsing line numbers is tricky. The ultimate goal is to convert something like `"11..18 1 3 4 9"` into `[1, 3, 4, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]`
- Using a modified `index_type()` (thanks to chepner), I was able to parse the command line from `"11..18 1 3 4 9"` to `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [1], [3], [4], [9]]`
- The next step is to convert this nested list into a set of line numbers for easy look up
- As a bonus, if the command line does not specify any line number, I assume `1..10`
- After `get_options` returns, `options.fileinput` will either be `None` or a file handle--no need to open the file to read. `options.selected_lines` will be a set of line numbers to select
- The final task is to go through the lines, if it is selected, process it. In my case, I just print it out

Comment: I was going to post something similar to this in my answer as well, but decided to focus on one approach for simplicity. `parse_known_args` is certainly a good option.